# PHP user class with login access

Tags: php, oop

I've searched something about a login system in Google but the thing is that I'm trying to get there by myself, and not following a guide that tells me everything.

I have an index.php that has a menu.php included in the top, which has an include for a login_form.php, which calls login.php to make the login.
In the login.php uses  the class User to make the login.
user.php has the `require_once` for the connection.php

I'm failing at something very easy to fix but can't quite see it as this is new to me. The problem is that an error happens:

> Undefined variable: mysql in admin\include\lib\user.php on line 12

connection.php:

```
 require_once 'constants.php';
 $mysql = new mysqli($db['host'], $db['username'], $db['password'], $db['name']);

if ($mysql->connect_error){
    die('Connection error (' . $mysql->connect_errno.')'. $mysql->connect_error);
}
```

user.php -> Line 12:

```
$this->password=$mysql->real_escape_string($this->password);
```

As a side note index.php as a require_once for the connection.php, constants.php (which has the $db array with the host, user, etc..), and the class.php.
I'm really trying to get in th OOP concept so I would really appreciate your help!

Thanks in advance guys!

EDIT:
I believe that it will be a bit hard to give you the file structure but I can assure you that I'm requiring things right. To prove it I did the `var_dump($mysql)`. If I call it in the user.php but outside the class User, it shows content. However if I call it inside the class User, it gives me the undefined error.

Comment: In user.php, try var_dump()ing $mysql to make sure it is what it should be.

Comment: Did you forget to include `connection.php` before you include `user.php`?  Or forget to include it **in** `user.php`?  (Obviously, I don't know how your files are laid out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a variable scope problem. `$mysql` is out of scope in the User class. I suggest passing the variable to the class in the constructor and store it as a property:

```
class User
{
    protected $mysql;   

    public function __construct($mysql)
    {
        $this->mysql = $mysql;
    }

    public function something()
    {
        $this->password = $this->mysql->real_escape_string($this->password);
    }
}
```

Example usage passing the connection:

```
require_once 'connection.php'; // creates $mysql
$user = new User($mysql);
```

Throughout the class you can now use `$this->mysql` to access the connection.

- More info about [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: First of all thanks. I actually understood what you said and I was exactly trying to find more on the class scope! I actually did that and then used another method for the login. That way when I construct I only tell it to create the $mysql like you said. Then on the method login I send parameters from the form to make the login. I believe it's that right?